# Why can't you use the types of TypeScript abstract classes to create React factories, when non-abstract classes work fine?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, abstract-class

The following Typescript code using React compiles and works just fine:

```
import * as React from "react";

class MyComponent<P> extends React.Component<P, any> {
    static getFactory() {
        return React.createFactory(this);
    }
}
```

However, the following code, similar in every way except the class is now abstract, throws an error at compilation, on the line where the factory is created:

```
import * as React from "react";

abstract class MyComponent<P> extends React.Component<P, any> {
    static getFactory() {
        return React.createFactory(this);
    }
}
```

The error is:

> error TS2345: Build:Argument of type 'typeof MyComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentClass<any> | StatelessComponent<any>'.

I can think of no reason why it should make a difference whether the class is marked as abstract or not.

Any insights as to why this might be the case?

================ADDED 9/22/2016=============

In my example above, I probably should have called `MyComponent` something like `MyBaseComponent`.  The whole point here is that I am creating a framework component that I never want instantiated.  I only want things derived from `MyComponent` to ever be instantiated.  (Note, for example, that `MyComponent` doesn't even have a `render()` method declared.)

So.... I declare a really-to-be-instantiated class as:

```
interface MyDerivedComponentProps {
    id: string;
}

class MyDerivedComponent extends MyComponent<MyDerivedComponentProps> {
    render() {
        return /* Some JSX rendering stuff here */
    }
}
```

Note that this all works just fine.... if I don't ever instantiate `MyComponent` but do instantiate `MyDerivedComponent`.  But the simple act of decorating `MyComponent` with the abstract keyword, which *ought* to serve to ensure that `MyComponent` will never be directly instantiated causes this compiler error.  And I'm still of the opinion that it shouldn't.  The compiler is handling the inheritance just fine if the base class is not marked as abstract.  It should also handle it fine if the base class is marked as abstract, or perhaps not, but if not, why?

================ADDED 9/29/2016=============

As per request in comments, here is a complete example code showing both declarations and inheritance for both:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

interface MyDerivedComponentProps {
    id: string;
}

// WORKING EXAMPLE
class MyBaseNonAbstractComponent<P> extends React.Component<P, any> {
    static getFactory() {
        return React.createFactory(this);  // NO COMPILER ERROR HERE
    }
}

class MyDerivedFromNonAbstractComponent extends MyBaseNonAbstractComponent<MyDerivedComponentProps> {
    render() {
        return <div>Hello from id {this.props.id}</div>;
    }
}

// NOT WORKING EXAMPLE
abstract class MyBaseAbstractComponent<P> extends React.Component<P, any> {
    static getFactory() {
        return React.createFactory(this); // HERE IS THE COMPILER ERROR
    }
}

class MyDerivedFromAbstractComponent extends MyBaseAbstractComponent<MyDerivedComponentProps> {
    render() {
        return <div>Hello from id {this.props.id}</div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(MyDerivedFromNonAbstractComponent.getFactory()({ id: "idForNonAbstract" }), document.getElementById("managed-content-for-non-abstract"));

ReactDOM.render(MyDerivedFromAbstractComponent.getFactory()({ id: "idForAbstract" }), document.getElementById("managed-content-for-abstract"));
```

================ADDED 9/29/2016 #2=============

It is definitely the case that whether or not a base class is marked abstract, if it has a static method on it, and that method refers to `this`, then it will actually dereference to the constructor of the derived class used to invoke the method.

So, if we have the following:

```
class BaseConcrete {
    static logWhoAmI() {
        console.log(`this is ${this}`);
    }
}

class DerivedConcrete extends BaseConcrete {
}

DerivedConcrete.logWhoAmI(); // This will log constructor of DerivedConcrete

abstract class BaseAbstract {
    static logWhoAmI() {
        console.log(`this is ${this}`);
    }
}

class DerivedAbstract extends BaseAbstract {
}

DerivedAbstract.logWhoAmI(); // This will log constructor of DerivedAbstract
```

So it appears that Typescript does not treat `this` referred to in a static method of a base class any differently when that base class is abstract or not.

It is only, somehow, the signature of the `React.createFactory()` method that seems to get confused somehow when passed the "this".  It complains because on the face of it, it seems as if it is being passed a constructor for an abstract method, which would of course be illegal.  But since the class itself is abstract, the `this` at runtime is guaranteed to be a derived class, and `React.createFactory` should work just fine.  In fact, as one commenter pointed out, if you cast the argument to `React.createFactory` to `any`, it will work fine at runtime.  But this is hack it seems to me.  Appreciate the discussion this far though.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce you issue using React 0.14 definitions and TS 1.8. What versions are you using ?

Comment: Hi @Bruno - I am using exactly what you descibe.  React 0.14 typings from DefinitelyTyped and TS 1.8.  But interesting to consider that this is perhaps fundamentally a typings problem.

Answer (score 2):

Abstract classes cannot be directly instantiated with `new` (that's why they are called so). Thus, you can't use them as React components. They can be the base classes for other components, though.

And that's the thing TypeScript compilers checks statically. Since abstract class doesn't have `new` operator, it cannot be coerced to ComponentClass.

Comment: Yes of course Abstract classes cannot be directly instantiated with new.  That is the whole point.  However, classes derived from the abstract class can be instantiated with new, and since the abstract class itself derives from the React.Component<P> class, any classes that derive from the abstract class will themselves derive from the React.Component<P> class, and can themselves be used to create classes.  That is exactly what is desired here.  I'll add a note to the main question though.

Comment: Still not clear in which line compiler gives such an error. According to the message, it's not declaration. Are you getting such an error just on inheritance?

Comment: HI @gaperton, in my second code snippet of the initial question, the error is showing up on line 5, the line "return React.createFactory(this);".  In the first code fragment, there is no error.

Comment: Hi. Show the complete code example, please. github repo, or whatever. We'll nail it down then. There are no miracles, after all. Just bugs.

Comment: The second snippet of code above is the complete code example.  That code, completely by itself, with React typings 0.14 from DefinitatelyTyped and using Typescript 1.8 is all the code needed to show this problem.  The first snippet is only showing code that is identical in every way except for the "abstract" keyword that works.  In my opinion, both snippets should compile down to the exact same Javascript, but the first one works and the second one throws a compiler error.

Comment: static getFactory() {
        return React.createFactory(this);
    }

I'm pretty sure the problem is in this method. It is defined in the abstract class. Therefore, 'this' type is 'typeof MyComponent', which cannot be instantiated because it's an abstract class. And because of that, it cannot be converted to the argument type accepted by React.createFactory.

Comment: So, it's exactly what I wrote in an answer.

Comment: No it isn't.  Because neither the working first snippet, nor the error-labelled second snippet instantiate a class.  But if you like, I will add the third snippet in to single not-working example that doesn't compile and should.  But it isn't relevant.

Comment: Yes, it is. TypeScript able to check whenever the class is abstract or not just looking at the coerced type. And argument type of createFactory() must not be an abstract class constructor.

Comment: So, 'this' inside of your method points to an abstract class constructor, which cannot be coerced to createFactory argument, which is must _not_ be an abstract class. It's ComponentClass<any> | StatelessComponent<any> - which is supposed to be instantiated with new. That's precisely how TypeScript should behave.

Comment: So I added the code.  In the working example, the correct factory based on the derived class is created and the correct derived class is instantiated.  In the non-working part, I would still expect the correct factory based on the derived class to be created, and the correct derived class to be instantiated.  Of course I can't test that because a compiler error gets in the way.  I don't see why this is correct.  I think Typescript should allow me to specify that I do NOT want anyone to ever instantiate the class MyBaseAbstractComponent directly, and only allow them to instantiate deriveds.

Comment: That is what the abstract keyword is for, is it not?

Comment: In other words, the "this" should (and I think does!) point not to the constructor of the base (possibly abstract) class, but to the derived class.

Comment: When TypeScript _compiles_ your abstract class, it have to compile your method somehow too, isn't it? Currently, this-type cannot be used in static functions (try, you'll see an error). So, it's inferred as your abstract class. So, you have an error.

Comment: I'm not going to argue is it theoretically right behavior or not, but it's how it works.

Comment: As a workaround you can cast it to <any>, that should fix the problem.

Comment: Well, thanks @gaperton.  You definitely deserve the bounty (which I have awarded) for your work on this question.  I appreciate it.  I have not marked this as the answer though, even though I upvoted it.  I am adding yet some more to the question.  I know you said you don't really want to argue what Typescript SHOULD do, and I respect that, but I am now thinking that this is a typings problem.  Your workaround does work, but it seems like a bit of a hack to me.  But thanks.

Comment: The problem is that you can invoke static method when you don't have an instance. Like `MyComponent<P>.getFactory()`. 'this' will be the MyComponent<P> constructor (which supposed to be abstract), and it's wrong. This is the situation TS is trying to prevent with such an error, I guess. I can see here the clear logic, at least.

Comment: Ah yes, I do see what you are saying.  And while I would (perhaps obvious from my comments this far) fall into the camp that would say "If Typescript can't discern a problem at runtime it should not throw an error, at worst it should throw a warning..." and I would further say that the warning in this case could be articulated more clearly, there is a way that if Typescript allowed me to write the code, I can do my own test to avoid the problem, namely `if (this === typeof(MyComponent<P>){throw new error("Illegal");}`.  Thanks.